# Series termination on receiver side?

Tags: pcb, analog, termination

I'm new to signal processing and have a specific question about a PCB design by TI. ([TDC7200EVM User’s Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snau177) ) ([TDC7200EVM](https://www.ti.com/tool/TDC7200EVM#technicaldocuments))

Could anyone explain why they place the series terminating resistors on the receiver side?

Is it not better to use parallel termination in this case?

Or am I completely wrong and these aren't terminating resistors?

[image: TDC7200EVM PCB design]

Comment: The TDC7200 datasheet says at the layout considerations: ```The length of the START and STOP traces from the TDC7200 to the stopwatch/MCU should be matched to prevent uneven signal delays. Also, avoid unnecessary via-holes on these traces and keep the routing as short/direct as possible to minimize parasitic capacitance on the PCB.``` I *think* they added R1 and R2 to get a better match. These 'big' resistors nihilate differences that are an order smaller, like solder joint resistance etc.

Comment: I can't figure out a good reason for those resistors, unless it's somehow related to the fact that the STOP & START inputs are Schmitt trigger inputs.  Also, their value of 49.9 ohms implies that they're 0.1% precision, which is way overkill for any kind of impedance matching use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answers.
[Texas Instruments kindly explained the reason for those resistors:](https://e2e.ti.com/support/sensors/f/1023/t/868758)

> The in-line resistance acts as part of a low-pass filter given the input capacitance is 3pF at the START and STOP pins. This is to prevent false-positives otherwise created by high-frequency transients-glitches at these pins.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer from TI.